# use of localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

hope you guys are having a wonderful day. I am currently learning `localStorage` and always faced some difficulties and I very appreciate that you guys help a lot to fix the issue.

I am currently building an application and it has a checkbox function what the checkbox function is about whenever items are checked and saved, I am trying to store the each of checked item's **current time** in my local storage and after a certain of time( lets say 10mins) the time that is stored in the storage is cleared.

I have tried to write some code but none of my code was not working so I just left it blank... and I am not sure If I explained well or not so what I am essentially trying to achieve is

**10:00 AM**

(O) Item A

(X) Item B

(X) Item C

> If `Item A` is checked at **10:00AM**, the countdown timer`(10mins)`
>   is triggered

**10:05 AM**

(O) Item A

(O) Item B

(X) Item C

> `Item B` is also selcted at 10:05AM and the countdown timer`(10 mins)` for Item B
>   is also triggered.

**10:10 AM**

`Something function` is called because `Item A` time is up.

**10:15 AM**

`Something function` is called because `Item B` time is up.

I was thinking to make the `setItem` for `timer` whenever the checkbox form is submitted but somehow it keeps making errors. Is there anyone who can help me out. I referred to some code I found from fiddle for making localstorage for timer but I am not sure how to apply it..  even just basics or general ideas to approach to what I am aiming to build. I will be very appreciated. I will leave the reference of fiddle on the comments

**JS:**

```
$('.item_class').on('click', function() {
    var item, selected_items = [];
    $('.item_class').each(function() { 
        item = {
              id    : $(this).attr('id')
            , value : $(this).prop('checked')
        };
        selected_items.push(item);

    } );

    $("#save").click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem();
    });

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5f5qexre/1/

Comment: You're not passing anything to local storage. should be: localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

Comment: Also your code is full of bugs. What exactly are you trying to do with this code, there may be a better approach than what you have going on here. A couple things I noticed right off the bat: .each should be more like .forEach() which takes function that takes an item.

Comment: JSFiddle appears to be disabling localStorage, check the dev console.